# Reading from assets file in android

Tags: java, android, assets

I'm working on a Hangman game to teach myself Android development.  I've done it all in Java already for PC and have that working well.  I'm using Android Studio 2.1 and the monitor keeps on throwing loads of errors at me and I can't make out what I'm looking at!

The part I'm struggling with is getting it to read from the file "WordsDoc" in assets.  The code I've got is:

**Edit 2**

All code for app so far (really not much!)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String strWord = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final TextView theWord = (TextView)
                findViewById(R.id.textViewWord);
        final EditText editTextGuess = (EditText)
                findViewById(R.id.editTextGuess);
        final Button buttonGuess = (Button)
                findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);
        final TextView theIncorrectGuesses = (TextView)
                findViewById(R.id.textViewIncorrectLetters);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alertMessage(this,"ERROR");
        strWord = getTheWord();
        theWord.setText(strWord);
        newGame();
        buttonGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                theIncorrectGuesses.setText("ABCDEF");
            }
        });
    }
    public String getTheWord() {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("WordsDoc.txt")));

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //process line
                lines.add(mLine);
            }
            int intLen = 0;
            String[] strWords = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
            for (String strTemp : strWords){
                intLen ++;
            }
            int intRand = (int)(Math.random()* intLen);
            return strWords[intRand];

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void newGame() {

    }
    public static void alertMessage(Activity a, String errMsg){

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(a);
        builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
        builder.setMessage(errMsg);
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        builder.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

**Edit 3**

Example of the file WordsDoc.txt is as below:

```
aardvark
Aarhus
Aaron
... continues 45000 more times
```

**Edit**

Errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxxx.hangman, PID: 4532
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.hangman/com.xxxx.hangman.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.xxxx.hangman.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    05-05 08:44:32.994 4532-4532/com.xxxx.hangman I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4532 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi added in edit.

Comment: Does you file name have any extension?

Comment: Nope. it's just WordsDoc

Comment: I think it should have an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the file with the extension:

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("WordsDoc.txt")))
      ...
```

**Edit:** Solution for my code:

You are trying to access the view before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) which is why your view are null.

Put this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

immediately after this:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

in your MainActivity. Like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // the rest goes here
```

Comment: I've changed it to a .txt file, and changed it in the code also, still no luck.  I've edited the original post to display all the code I have so far.

Comment: What type of file is that actually ? I was just giving an example. Changing like that won't work

Comment: The file had no extension before, I've now changed it to a .txt extension as that's the only logical one for it.  Included an edit which shows an example of the file.

Comment: Many thanks, what an idiot I am, such a basic thing haha.

Comment: Glad it helped you